# how to logging debug level to file but only info level on screen in python

Tags: python, logging

in my python project i have several lines that are logging with debug level and other with info level. Now, when i run my code i can set at the begging the log level to info or debug level and that will log to a file and on the screen only the info or both info/debug messages accordingly.

How can i achieve to set to log to file always debug level but on screen always info level?

Example (only a small part):

```
loggername = 'Main.Case.'
self.logger = logging.getLogger(loggername)
self.logger.info('case() - Started')
self.logger.debug('System ready...')
self.logger.debug('File ready...')
self.logger.debug('Memory ready...')
self.logger.info('case() - Ready')
```

This would print with info level only (on screen and log file):

```
Main.Case.case() - Started
Main.Case.case() - Ready
```

With debug level i will get (on screen and log file):

```
Main.Case.case() - Started
Main.Case.System ready...
Main.Case.File ready...
Main.Case.Memory ready...
Main.Case.case() - Ready
```

I actually would like to have on screen always only the info level lines and in the log file info/debug level!

When i activate debug level then i will get everything to both out puts (screen/file).

Any one any idea??

Thanks in adv.

Comment: RTM. The python [logging docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) show you how to create stream and file handlers. use `setLevel` to set the logger to `DEBUG` and the handlers to `INFO` or `DEBUG`. Besides the docs, there are lots of examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing to screen and writing to a file at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321741/printing-to-screen-and-writing-to-a-file-at-the-same-time)

Comment: See this possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652727/different-logging-levels-for-filehandler-and-display-in-python

Comment: Thanks, next time i will search more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do this exact thing is documented in the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations) in the Python docs.